# Line graphs of Powers of Cycles are powers of cycles

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics

Are line graphs of powers of cycles again a power of cycle? I think yes, this is because the line graphs of cycles are cycles of the same order, and moreover, since powers of cycles consist of edge disjoint cycles which are packed within a distance given by the value of the power, their line graphs also must be powers of cycles. Am I right?

The definition of power is use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) one. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Have you tried a formal approach, i.e. writing down a _formal_ definition of some cycle power and its line graph?

Comment: I don't think your claim can be true. Try to find a counter-example. Hint: consider the second power of some cycle $C_k$ for some fixed $k$. Can its line graph also be a line graph of a cycle?

Comment: @DiscreteLizard my claim is that the line graph of a power cycle is some other power of a cycle. In your example, my claim is that the line graph of the square of $C_k$ is isomorphic to the cube of $C_{2k}$.

Comment: @vidyarthi Ok. I think the claim in your question may be true. But the square of the line graph of $C_k$ would only be isomorphic to a power of $C_{\min \{2k, k(k-1)/2 \}}$.